# Deleted User plus Accepted Answers Preventing Max Daily Rep?

Tags: bug, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, reputation-history

A little bit ago, I had a rep of 37,911.  It dropped to 37,901 because of the event

> -10    1 hour ago removed User was removed

My total rep for the day is now 224.  Given that I have 2 accepted answers today, my max reputation should be 230.

I had upvotes for which I did not receive credit today, including:

Question upvoted (+5)

[Coping with Lagging Enum Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185116/coping-with-lagging-enum-support)

Answer upvoted (credited +10 for 2 upvotes)

[Convert .db to binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850564/convert-db-to-binary/11850633#11850633)

Answer upvoted (credited +10 for 2 upvotes)

[Make a copy of Database by converting its units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850511/make-a-copy-of-databse-by-converting-its-units/11850581#11850581)

In the past, I have seen that a dip in daily reputation due to such an event is filled in within several minutes using any excess, uncredited reputation from other events.  That does not seem to be happening in this particular case.

All of these events happened "today" (ending 5PM Pacific, midnight UTC).

Bug?  Do I need glasses?

Comment: @HDE226868 Why reject edit? Please see the typo "Databse" in the post where it says: *Make a copy of Databse by converting its units*

Comment: @HackerKarma: The link text in my original version was auto-generated from the original title of the question.  Not sure what your edit was, but I fixed it up now to match the correct title of the question.

Comment: Eric, that's ok and I understand but apparently these reviewers who rejected the edit becoz did not noticed my change. Here is what they saw: http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/39936 Both looks the same in the "rendered output" BUT, toggle to "markdown" and you will see what I actually edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removals are not calculated in the reputation cap. They're merely notices to inform you of why you lost reputation suddenly. The *actual* recalculation for reputation caps occurs back on the day the votes were originally received.

You have 200 reputation from upvotes, 30 reputation from accepted answers, and 4 reputation from accepting answers. Your current standing for the day is 234. You lost 10 reputation from a removal, so your **net gain** for the day is 224.

Comment: Somewhat confusing, but logically consistent :-)

Comment: I see the correct daily total here: http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: @EricJ: You might be interested in [Separate and visually indicate reversal events from the day's reputation changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146682/separate-and-visually-indicate-reversal-events-from-the-days-reputation-changes)