# Show removed posts in reputation history by default

Tags: feature-request, reputation

It seems the only use for the "show removed posts" checkbox in the user reputation history is to cause endless "did you check "show removed posts"" comments on Meta questions where users don't get how their rep adds up. It presumably also causes lots of confusion  when people aren't aware of the setting.

I really don't see a reason for this checkbox other than to confuse and annoy. I'm sure that's not the intent, but it's the effect. I suggest that it should default to *on* at the least...or even better the function should be removed all together and you should just show the posts. They're not actually hidden except through an awkward UI, so I don't see any use here.

Comment: But how do you know how many people aren't whining about deleted content right now precisely because they don't know about the checkbox? :P

Comment: I do have a feeling you're right though, now that they implemented the whole retaining reputation for old, deleted content shenanigans I doubt hiding the deletion indicators is all that useful.

Comment: I sometimes use the checkbox, actually. Turning it off lets me see my *actual* reputation value for the day (that counts towards the Legendary badge) without having to do any math. Of course, if [something like this were implemented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146682), then that reason would be gone too.

Comment: @animuson hadn't thought of that; implimenting both features seems like the best way to alleviate both headaches and all reason for the checkbox.