# Rep cap and user removed

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-history

Weird thing, I'm not sure if it's intentional design, so I'm asking here. On one site, yesterday I reached rep cap but then some votes were cancelled saying "User was removed". Now, the weird thing is that those votes still seem to count towards the cap, effectively “limiting” me to a lower cap:

[image: Weird rep cap]

Is that correct?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is intentional and by design. When something (a user or a post) is removed, the votes are removed from the day they are cast. Therefore they are subject to those days' repcaps and not the day they were removed.

So if you didn't repcap those days, then it will deduct from your total.

If you go to your [reputation audit page](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), you will see that you have gained +200 yesterday.

Comment: Well, indicating +179 in the stats page is not a very clear way of telling me I gain +200 :)

Comment: Yeah, it's kinda counter-intuitive. But that's just the way it is.

Comment: @F'x: Related: [Separate and visually indicate reversal events from the day's reputation changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146682/separate-and-visually-indicate-reversal-events-from-the-days-reputation-changes)

Comment: Does that day count towards the epic/legendary badge? cc @animuson

Comment: @Yez I believe it does. But don't quote me on it.