# Rep in User Dropdown doesn't match rep in User Profile sometimes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, profile-page, activity-dropdown

I've noticed this a few times where the reputation in the user dropdown

[image: Rep Dropdown 190]

doesn't match the reputation in the user profile

[image: User Profile Rep 160]

It doesn't appear to be a caching issue, and I've refreshed plenty of times.  There have been similar problems brought up on Meta before, but this seems different.

**Edit:** The -30 difference appears to be because in the User Profile some rep that was marked `removed` is subtracted out, but it's not subtracted out of the dropdown reputation.

[image: Removed Reputation]

Comment: This is because the -30 for a removal doesn't actually affect your reputation for *today* but your reputation for the day(s) that gained you that reputation. The drop-down is the accurate one, and my [proposed feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146682/separate-and-visually-indicate-reversed-events-from-the-days-reputation-changes) would prevent this confusion in your reputation history. *Unchecking* the "show removed posts" option should show you the correct value for today in your reputation history.

Comment: So are we sure that the rep doesn't affect today's totals?  I guess if get some upvotes today I'll see if I cap out.

Comment: No, it doesn't. If you have removed posts shown and hit the rep cap today, it will *appear* as if you hit the rep cap at 170 (when you get 10 more) because that -30 is calculated into your net for the day, but not counted towards the actual rep cap. That's why so many people get confused when removed posts are shown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Removed posts are not reflected in the dropdown as they are in your profile with the preference you have checked (which isn't the default).  We only cache one value, not every variant (there are 4).

If you uncheck "show removed posts" on your reputation tab you'll see the values match.