# Reputation discrepancy between user drop down and user page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I had and answer unaccept today and received -15 rep for that. This is included in the total reputation and my reputation on the user page (200 for the day is correct) but in the user drop down at the top of the page it's not included (it shows 215 for the day). The unaccept happened a few hours ago so it doesn't seem to be a matter of waiting for refresh.

[image]

Comment: Unaccepts indeed do not show up in the dropdown; by design, I believe.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's interesting. Why it would be so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user drop-down at the top does not include any reversal events (unupvote, undownote, reversal, removed are all excluded) because those aren't actual events that are occurring for that day, they are *reversals* of events that occurred on previous days.

It is in fact the number in the reputation history that is incorrect. I've [proposed a fix for that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146682/separate-and-visually-indicate-reversed-events-from-the-days-reputation-changes) though.