# Weird rep cap behavior, yesterday vs. today

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Yesterday, I got 230 reputation points from upvotes and two accepted answers; several upvotes didn't give me points because of the rep cap.

Today, a question I answered was on the front page of Hacker News, and my answer got (so far) 276 upvotes; obviously I hit the rep cap today.

Also today, a question I had answered was deleted, and I lost the 60 points from my answer.

No complaints so far.

Here's the odd thing. My score for yesterday is now 280 points (50 points were added, apparently for upvotes that had previously not counted because I had passed the 200-point rep cap).  My current score for today is 150 points, and new upvotes are not increasing today's score, so I'll be stuck at 150 unless I get an accepted answer or a bounty.

Ok, so the 50 points from previously uncounted upvotes were added to yesterday's score (increasing it from 230 to 280) and not to today's score (which would have increased it from 150 to 200).  So I can't really say it's unfair, but it does seem counterintuitive.

Is this the intended behavior? (I presume the answer to that is yes.)

Is the rep cap documented somewhere in sufficient detail that I could have predicted this?

**UPDATE :**

As Mysticial points out, if I uncheck "show removed posts", my displayed points change from 280 yesterday, 150 today to 230 yesterday, 200 today.

A closely related question: given the inconsistent display of daily reputation, depending on whether "show removed posts" is checked, do both days contribute to the Legendary badge (earn 200 daily rep 150 times), or just yesterday? (Personally I think both should, but not everything can be 100% fair.) Whatever the answer, I'd say that the inconsistent point display is a bug.

Comment: Yes, this is intended behavior. The loss of 50 was from yesterday as far as repcap calculations are done. But the actual loss of rep happened today. If you uncheck the "show removed posts" box, then it looks normal again.

Comment: Sounds more like a bug to me. ;-)

Comment: @Oded♦: You marked this "status-bydesign", but I think there's still a bug; see the updated last 2 paragraphs.

Comment: @KeithThompson - The display is by design, and I believe both days will count towards the repcap.

Answer (score 4):

It's very intended. Those 5 upvotes from the deleted post have now "never occurred" (as far as the system is concerned), so it would be unfair to still cap your votes from that day even though you're not actually gaining the reputation from the deleted post. The actual problem here is that the +50 that you have not actually gained anymore is still being mixed into everything, which is causing the confusion. I've [proposed a fix for that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146682/separate-and-visually-indicate-reversed-events-from-the-days-reputation-changes) which would exclude reversed events from the number next to each day, and push them down to the bottom to emphasize that they're not being counted.

Similarly, the -60 for today is being calculated into the total, but is not actually counting towards anything for that day.