# My reputation yesterday didn't hit the daily rep cap, so why didn't I get rep for these upvotes?

Tags: support, reputation

I'm confused about how much reputation I should have earned yesterday:

[image: Screenshot]

According to [my reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/456814/cupcake?tab=reputation), I earned 192 net reputation yesterday. However, as you can see in the upper-left hand corner of the screenshot, I stopped earning rep on upvotes to this answer:

- [What are the differences between double-dot ".." and triple-dot "..." in Git commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462974/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-com/24186641#24186641)

I also didn't earn any rep for the upvote on this answer:

- [Taking a git diff and creating a new branch in different repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922094/taking-a-git-diff-and-creating-a-new-branch-in-different-repo/24922587#24922587)

When I go to [`stackoverflow.com/reputation`](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), it tells me I did indeed hit the rep cap yesterday:

```
-- 2014-07-22 rep +102  = 21237     
 2  23961231 (10)
 2  24186641 (10)
 2  21616766 (5)
 2  24417188 (10)
 2  24186641 (10)
 2  24580837 (10)
 2  24186641 (10)
 2  24878977 (10)
 2  17848593 (10)
 3  -------- (-1)
 3  -------- (-1)
 2  23961231 (10)
 2  23961231 (10)
 2  24166311 (10)
 3  -------- (-1)
 2  17517343 (10)
 2  24186641 (10)
 2  24914043 (10)
 2  23217431 (10)
 3  -------- (-1)
 2  24186641 (10)
 2  23415303 (10)
 2  24186641 (10)
 2  17643063 (10)
 2  24186641 [9]
 2  24186641 [0]
 2  24186641 [0]
 2  24186641 [0]
 2  24922587 [0]
 2  23415303 [0]
-- 2014-07-23 rep +200  = 21437
```

So I thought maybe the daily rep cap is based on your **public** reputation, vs your private rep that you see due to losing rep on downvoting answers. Yet I only downvoted 6 answers on that day, which leaves 2 rep un-accounted for, and I also recovered some of that lost rep when the downvoted answers were removed.

I read in [Weird rep cap behavior, yesterday vs. today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200148/weird-rep-cap-behavior-yesterday-vs-today) that I could un-check that "show removed posts" setting at the bottom of the reputation tab, but even after I did that, it told me that I had only earned 190 rep.

Here's the **public view** of my reputation for that day:

[image]

**Can anyone please explain to me how much net reputation I actually earned yesterday, and whether or not it counts toward the Legendary badge?**

Comment: See my answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144512/unupvote-immediately-followed-by-an-upvote-gives-me-a-net-10-reputation-points I'll stop short of closing as dupe since I don't know what effect it has on repcap badges.

Comment: Do any of the four "+1 removed" events correspond to any of the "-1 downvoted" events (as in they got removed the same day after you cast your downvote)?

Comment: @animuson none of the -1s from http://stackoverflow.com/reputation correspond to deleted answers. Only one of the answers that I downvoted on that day was removed, and its ID doesn't show up in the list from the reputation url.

Comment: Only one? I would have assumed it'd be two. I see six downvoted entries but only four in your reputation log. I was just curious if two of the removed entries matched up.

Comment: @Mysticial I can see how the whole unupvote+upvote sequence would result in a net loss of -10 to my total rep if I'm already capped for the day, but I don't understand how that could cause my daily rep for that day to display as anything less than 200.

Comment: @animuson yup, it's only one `:/`

Comment: If I uncheck the "show removed posts", then it shows me 190 rep for yesterday, which would seem to support Mysticial's theory that it's the unupvote+upvote sequence that causes the discrepency...but I still don't see how that could cause my *daily* rep to be below 200 if the system know that I've hit the rep cap.

Comment: The daily rep that you see in your profile is the net change in rep for the day. But the repcap is an independent system. The repcap caps you to 200 from votes that are cast on day X. But the net change in rep on X is affected by more than that (including removal of votes from previous days.)

Comment: Mysticial's link doesn't explain this. In that case, they received +0 for the new upvote because of the cap. You did received +10 for your new upvote. You should see 190 in the default public view, because you gained 200 for the *that day* and lost 10 from *some other day*. I think it's the weird combination of downvotes and removals that is throwing us off here. As a moderator, I'm seeing 198 for that day which just makes me more confused. We've got four different numbers going here.

Comment: @animuson alright, I'm willing to let the whole rep count issue go because the system is so complicated, but now I just need someone to explain to me what ends up counting for the Legendary badge `:/`

Comment: Are you absolutely sure only one of the posts you downvoted was deleted? Can you check them all? Because all of this would make a lot of sense if two of them were deleted. It's just a lot of weird math. But the system thinks you earned 200 reputation that day, so it should count towards your Legendary badge, regardless of how messed up the history is.

Comment: @animuson I've double-checked again, [this is the only answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24909383/456814) that shows up as having been deleted yesterday (UTC). [This answer was also eventually deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24900933/456814), but it was deleted *today*, as far as the system is concerned.

Comment: @Cupcake Aha, one sec. I think I know where all these numbers are coming from (and why it showed me 199 yesterday, but 198 today).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### In *your* standard view (with removed posts hidden by default): *190*

What's being counted:

```
+0   upvote
+0   upvote
+0   upvote
+9   upvote
+60  upvote (x6 grouped together for convenience)

+30  upvote (x3 grouped together for convenience)

+0   upvote
+10  upvote

+80  upvote (x8 separate posts grouped together for convenience)
+5   upvote
+0   upvote

+10  upvote
-10  unupvote (deleted upvote from previous day)

-1   downvoted
-1   downvoted
-1   downvoted
-1   downvoted
-1   downvoted (now deleted)
-1   downvoted (now deleted)

+1   removed
+1   removed
+1   removed
+1   removed
```

So that day, in the end, resulted in you gaining an additional +4 reputation to compensate for the four downvotes that you had cast that day, resulting in a total of 204 reputation gained, and 4 reputation lost from downvoting.

You see 190 because that -10 for the unupvote doesn't actually count for that day. It's merely an informative record, telling you that you just lost (potentially) 10 reputation from an upvote that was cast on some other day. I say potentially because if you were capped on that other day, you may have gained it from another vote automatically an experienced no actual change.

### In *your* view with removed posts shown: *192*

What's being counted:

```
+0   upvote
+0   upvote
+0   upvote
+9   upvote
+60  upvote (x6 grouped together for convenience)

+30  upvote (x3 grouped together for convenience)

+0   upvote
+10  upvote

+80  upvote (x8 separate posts grouped together for convenience)
+5   upvote
+0   upvote

+10  upvote
-10  unupvote (deleted upvote from previous day)

-1   downvoted
-1   downvoted
-1   downvoted
-1   downvoted
-1   downvoted (now deleted)
-1   downvoted (now deleted)

+1   removed
+1   removed
+1   removed
+1   removed
```

Now, those six removed posts are being thrown into the mix too. That results in an additional -2 from the downvotes you cast, and an additional +4 from removed posts, resulting in a net of +2 in that total.

### In the *public view*: *194*

What's being counted:

```
+0   upvote
+0   upvote
+0   upvote
+9   upvote
+60  upvote (x6 grouped together for convenience)

+30  upvote (x3 grouped together for convenience)

+0   upvote
+10  upvote

+80  upvote (x8 separate posts grouped together for convenience)
+5   upvote
+0   upvote

+10  upvote
-10  unupvote (deleted upvote from previous day)

-1   downvoted
-1   downvoted
-1   downvoted
-1   downvoted
-1   downvoted (now deleted)
-1   downvoted (now deleted)

+1   removed
+1   removed
+1   removed
+1   removed
```

This one really gets interesting. Standard users do not have access to see the posts you've downvoted *or* see removed posts in other user's reputation history. So all of your downvoted and removed events get ignored when calculating the total of what another user sees. Since the system compensated you an additional +4 reputation past normal to account for those downvotes you cast, it *looks* like you've miraculously gained 204 reputation that day for no apparent reason (and of course, that unupvote knocks the total down to 194).

### In a *moderator's view*: *198*

What's being counted:

```
+0   upvote
+0   upvote
+0   upvote
+9   upvote
+60  upvote (x6 grouped together for convenience)

+30  upvote (x3 grouped together for convenience)

+0   upvote
+10  upvote

+80  upvote (x8 separate posts grouped together for convenience)
+5   upvote
+0   upvote

+10  upvote
-10  unupvote (deleted upvote from previous day)

-1   downvoted
-1   downvoted
-1   downvoted
-1   downvoted
-1   downvoted (now deleted)
-1   downvoted (now deleted)

+1   removed
+1   removed
+1   removed
+1   removed
```

Like regular users, moderators cannot see what posts you downvoted. **But** we can see removed posts in other user's profiles. Catch-22: since those removed posts regained you +1 reputation each because they were posts you had previously downvoted, those events still don't actually show up for moderators. They *do*, however, get calculated into the overall total for the day as being a removed post. This adds an *additional* +4 to our view of your reputation, making it look like you miraculously gained 208 reputation that day.

---

To answer your ultimate question, though: **yes, you gained 200 reputation that day and it will count towards your Legendary badge**. This is just one hell of a confusing mess caused by the reputation history.

Comment: This makes my head hurt. I think it's going to take a while for me to finally understand how all the numbers add up (is this what accountants do all day?). Thanks though for putting in the time and effort to try and sort all of this out.