# Seems like rep cap exceeded with +360 rep in upvotes in one day

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

It *seems* like [this user's reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679863/rohit-jain?tab=reputation) for 2013-10-18 ("yesterday" as of this posting), has somehow exceeded the rep cap. His rep for the day is:

- 4 x accept (15) = 60
- 34 x counted upvote (10) = 340
- other upvotes that did not count (due to rep cap)
- no other rep activity (bounties etc)
- Total **400**

My understanding is that the maximum should have been 260, 200 in upvotes (capped) plus the 4 accepts (60).

How is it that so many upvotes counted?

If it's legitimate, I like to learn how he did it :)

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the immediately following "-140 serial voting reversal"?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a serial upvote reversed, so you will find a corresponding -140 a day later. So

```
200 rep: normal cap
 60 rep: 4 accepts, which are not capped
140 rep: not counted because it was reversed

400 rep: total for the day.
```

[image: repcap]

Serial upvoting happens when someone indiscriminately upvotes answers of a different account. In this case, 14 upvotes were invalidated the next day, bringing the rep total for the previous day 140 *under* the repcap. In consequence, 14 other up votes, which previously brought no rep because of the cap, are since counted as positive rep.

Comment: Sure, but why did the 140 count the day before? Shouldn't it just be -140 on the day later? Doesn't that mean there's a net zero for the minus now? (I don't even know what a serial upvote is btw)

Comment: @Bohemian The day gets recalculated upon a reversal as if those votes had never occurred. You might be interested in [this proposal of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146682/separate-and-visually-indicate-reversed-events-from-the-days-reputation-changes) which would make that clearer.

Comment: I get how it was reversed, but I don't get why it counted the day before. Why is it not just 260 for the day? Presumably the reversal is supposed to be a negative impact, it appears here as if it's a neutral impact

Comment: @Bohemian Because those votes were not capped originally - other votes amounting to 140 reputation got capped and thus didn't count. Upon  reversing them the following day, you gained 140 from other votes the previous day to compensate.

Comment: @animuson got it. for something that complex, putting in an explanatory item as you suggested would be the easy part.