# Reputation counter stops before reaching 200

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, daily-reputation-limit

Yesterday, my reputation on the Aviation site was limited to 190 for the day. After it reached 190, two answers received additional up votes: [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/45643/21091) and [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/45703/21091). My daily reputation can be viewed in the history [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/21091/koyovis?tab=reputation).

When I checked last with the reputation counter @ 190, the up votes for the answers were around 35 and 10. When checking again in the morning (my morning, = around 2200 UTC), votes were around 44 and 14, with a Guru medal awarded for the helicopter answer - but reputation still at 190 for the day.

What gives?

Comment: Rather than talking about total votes, it's probably easier to look at your reputation history page: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/21091/koyovis?tab=reputation It looks like you received one unupvote but that was early in the day, long before you rep capped. It's possible that the system, for some reason, failed to account for it. Usually an unupvote will just free the space for additional upvoting. You had 22 surplus upvotes, so you *should* have rep capped yesterday.

Comment: Yes, but rep capped at 200 not 190 correct?

Comment: Yes. The rep cap is 200 points (excludes bounties, accepts).

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146682/separate-and-visually-indicate-reversed-events-from-the-days-reputation-changes

Comment: Ah yes, deleting and undeleting an answer fixed the wrong cap of yesterday. Clearly a known bug then.

Comment: @animuson There seems to be another instance of this, where deleting and undeleting does not help. On 4 December 2017, rep should have been capped at 200, indicates 199 instead.

Comment: @Koyovis You downvoted an answer near the very end of the day, which cost you 1 reputation. You only get that 1 reputation back from votes that occur *after* the downvote. So if you had gotten another upvote in the 47 minutes that were left of that day, that upvote would have given you 1 reputation back. Upvotes received before subsequent downvotes do not counter the reputation lost from those downvotes.

Comment: @animuson Interesting, is that by design? Anyway, the single point loss is not very important, except for the count in reaching the daily max. I seem to have lost a count in recent days, went from 41 to 42 despite reaching the cap twice. Was wondering if some sort of system recount only looked at the day end score, and did not count that day.

Comment: @Koyovis Yes, that's by design. It doesn't make a lot of sense for votes that occur before another to be able to compensate for the latter. I'm honestly not sure how often that count gets updated, but I've seen a lot of reports of it being somewhat inaccurate at times. Keep in mind that negative reputation events (like downvotes in either direction) are not considered in calculations for the Legendary badge class. It's literally just *earned* at least 200 that day. The only thing that would make a day stop counting in the future is if vote(s) for that day got reverted somehow.